# Cómo traer el valor de una tabla referenciada de otra en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Buena tarde para todos,

Tengo una vista donde me muestra los valores de mi tabla ordenes, esta tabla está referenciada con otra llamada pacientes, y ésta última con una tabla llamada ciudades. el problema que tengo es que el campo ciudades no me lo muestra con la ciudad sino con el id de la ciudad.

por ejemplo para los campos: nombre, empresa, cargo, ciudad...

me muestra...

juan |Google | TI  |  1

y quisiera que me mostrara...

juan |Google | TI  |Bogota

Gracias de antemano.

OrdenController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\CreateOrdenRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateOrdenRequest;
use App\Repositories\OrdenRepository;
use App\Http\Controllers\AppBaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Flash;
use Prettus\Repository\Criteria\RequestCriteria;
use Response;
use App\Models\Ciudad;
use App\Models\Orden;
use App\Models\Paciente;

class OrdenController extends Controller
{
    /** @var  OrdenRepository */
    private $ordenRepository;

    public function __construct(OrdenRepository $ordenRepo)
    {
        $this->ordenRepository = $ordenRepo;
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $this->ordenRepository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($request));
        $ordenes = $this->ordenRepository->all();
        return view('ordenes.index')->with('ordenes', $ordenes)->with('paciente_Orden'); 
      /*return view('ordenes.index')->with('ordenes', $ordenes);**/    
    }

    public function create(){

           $ciudad = ['' => ''] + Ciudad::pluck('nombre','id')->toArray();

    return view('ordenes.create', compact('ciudad','orden'));

        if (empty($orden)) {
            Flash::error('Orden no encontrada');

            return redirect(route('ordenes.index'));
        }
    }



}
```

OrdenModel

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Orden extends Model
{

    public $table = 'ordenes';

      public function paciente_Orden(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Paciente','id','id_paciente');
    }

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';

    public $fillable = [
        'id',
        'id_paciente',
        'empresa',
        'cargo'    
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'id_paciente' => 'integer',
        'empresa' => 'string',
        'cargo'=> 'string'
    ];

    public static $rules = [

    ];
}
```

table.blade

```
<table class="table" id="orden-tabla">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Empresa</th>
            <th>Cargo</th>
            <th>Ciudad</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($ordenes as $orden)
        <tr>
            <td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->nombre !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $orden->empresa !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $orden->cargo !!}</td>
            <td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->id_ciudad !!}</td>

            <td>
                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['ordenes.destroy', $orden->id], 'method' => 'delete','style'=>'margin-left: 14%;']) !!}
                <div class='btn-group'>
            </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

En caso de que las relaciones estén dadas de alta en tus modelos orden, paciente y ciudad en lugar de:

```
<td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->id_ciudad !!}</td>
```

Escribe esto:

```
<td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->ciudad !!}</td>
```

O como esté especificado el nombre del campo "ciudad" en tu base de datos.

Si no, establece las relaciones en el modelo paciente, algo como:

```
public funcion ciudad() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Ciudad');
}
```

Y la función inversa para el modelo ciudades:

```
public function paciente() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Paciente');
}
```

Al hacer esto debería permitirte ver la relación entre las tablas como:

```
{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->ciudad->ciudad !!}
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Gracias Jesús por tu respuesta, me aclaraste varias dudas que tenia, lo resolví de la siguiente manera:

En mi Modelo Paciente

```
public function ciudad_paciente(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ciudad','id','id_ciudad');
}
   public function ingreso_paciente(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Ingreso','id_paciente','id');
    }
```

y en mi table.blade

```
 <td>{!! $orden->paciente_Orden->ciudad_paciente->nombre !!}</td>
```